# what's wrong in this sql?

Tags: sql

```
select id from dm_unit where aa like '%'||?||'%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the internal single quotes, this can be done by doubling them:

```
select id from dm_unit where aa like '%''||?||''%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner quotes need to be escaped?

```
select id from dm_unit where aa like '%\'||?||\'%'
```

Comment: Or doubled... Or perhaps || is the concatenation operator and ? is a place holder for prepared statements. That's why we need to know the SQL dialect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the `?` as a placeholder. If this is the case, the query should
read `select id from dm_unit where aa like ?` and the placeholder's value should later on be bound to something like `'%foobar%'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote \' in your query to use single quote in your query. but its not a right way. to use single quote in our query use '' (2 single quote) instead of ' (1 single quote)

Answer (score 0):

sorry i am not giving an answer I just want to understand why not to use : `LIKE '%?%'`

Comment: Because it's not a valid placeholder, since the question mark is contained within the string and therefore won't be understood. Also if you have a question that refers to someone elses answer you should leave a comment instead of making a new answer.

Comment: Thanks James :)
by the way, i dont find how to comment the question instead of post an answer